# Postgres: What is the difference between regexp_match vs regexp_matches

Tags: sql, postgresql

What is the difference between `regexp_match` vs `regexp_matches` in Postgres.
For the below query both yields the same result

```
select (regexp_match('foobarbequebaz', '(bar)(beque)'));
select (regexp_matches('foobarbequebaz', '(bar)(beque)'));
```

When to use over the other option? Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: The  docs [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html) explain it.

Comment: The difference is the same as between `text[]` and `setof text[]`

Answer (score 0):

regex_pmatch returns `text[]` while regexp_matches returns `setof text[]`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html for more information.